# required fields skip reactions to user input

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, lifecycle, required

If there are empty `required` fields in the form, they prevent me both from setting the values via code and hide/show other fields depending on current user input.
I broke down my problem to a tiny example:

```
<h:inputText label="Name" value="#{req.test}" required="true"/>
<h:inputText label="Details" value="#{req.tests2}" readonly="true" required="true"/>

<h:selectBooleanCheckbox label="Hide field" value="#{req.bool1}"/>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not req.bool1}">
    <h:inputText label="Hidden" value="#{req.test3}" required="true"/>
</ui:fragment>
```

I have `required` fields in my form, but if the user chooses to first set the checkbox, I want the hidden field to appear even if the validation failed. And I want the fields to be marked as invalid, so I cannot use immediate.

---

The problem is that while processing validation, **renderResponse is called in the jsf lifecycle**. So the update model values phase is skipped and I cannot react to the user input.

In addition to that: If I fill all `required` fields with the checkbox checked (the form would be valid) and uncheck the checkbox (a `required` field `"Hidden"` appears), I **cannot** just make `"Hidden"` to disappear again by checking the checkbox, because `"Hidden"` cannot be empty as `required` field. **Even if** I say `required="#{not req.bool1}"` it does not work, as the checkbox value never reaches my model because the update model value phase is skipped.

What we did now is wrap the faces context to prevent a call to `renderResponse()` during the validation phase from setting the flag. (Yes, dangerous, yes, I do need a better way to do that.) Now finally the model is up to date, **BUT**:
The required fields still remain empty, because for some reason jsf decided `required` fields do not need to get their value from my model as long as they are empty/invalid.

1. How can I make my model **values** to appear in the **`required` fields**?
2. Is there a **simple and proper way** to solve my ignore-invalid-state-and-continue-with-phases-properly problem, **other than basically preventing `renderResponse()`** from happening?

Comment: Add support of ajax to your h:selectBooleanCheckbox UI element: event="click" render="id", with rendering @form or fragment's parent

Comment: So you mean I'd need to update the form every time I change some field that changes the required fields' values in my model? Unfortunately that doesn't work, because as I said for some reason jsf decided that empty required fields don't need to update their value from the model. Every other field shows its value, just the required fields stay empty.

Comment: But thanks for the hint with ajax... I'm doing this in the code now. After resetting the component, it does update correctly:
`UIInput ui = ...get the reqired field by id; 
ui.resetValue();
Ajax.update(ui.getClientId());`
Now the values show. The fields still have an invalid status, as during the validation phase they were still empty, but well. I can live with that for now, I guess...
But is that workaround really the only way to mark fields invalid and still react to other user input? My solution seems to be way too complicated to do such a basic thing.

Comment: @BalusC Sorry for the wrong tag, I wasn't sure the highlighting worked without it... Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to the first question is: reset the value and THEN update, then I get my values to show in the required fields. Thanks Vasil!

As for the second question: I wonder how it's possible no one ran into the problem before. Is it just me? Well, I guess I'm not getting the point and am using the life cycle wrong or something. But I was really thinking the view should respond to user input, even it some fields are still empty. The user is still inserting data after all, and we're not moving on, yet. The fields are allowed to be empty in that state.
I guess that's the point and my "required" means something else than the jsf "required". I still don't get the standard validation process in that regard...

But I have a dirty workaround for my problem, so I'll mark the question as answered.